# Using Powershells Trimstart to remove array of characters from filename

Tags: powershell, trim, readonly

I'm trying to do a simple bulk file rename to remove non-standard characters (e.g. " 0123456789-_.") from the start of a filename and just add a string to the filename.

e.g. '12 -_myfilename.doc' would become '012345 - myfilename.doc'

...where 012345 is my study number. I've tried using the script below but keep on getting the following error when stepping through the script executing the trimstart line...

"'Name' is a ReadOnly" property"

I guess that this is not a trimstart problem but the way in which I'm attempting to gather the result from it.

Any help appreciated.

The relevant part of the code looks like...

```
$MyFileObject=0
if ($MyRecursiveFlag) {
Get-ChildItem $MyStudyPath -recurse | where {$_.extension -in ".xls",”.xlsx”,".xslt",".pdf",".doc",".docx",".xlsm",".xml",".htm",".ppt"}|
ForEach-Object{

    #Check if start of the file is compliant
    $mymatch = [Regex]::Match($_, '\d{5}\s-\s')
    if ($mymatch.Success){
        #Already renamed correctly so nothing else to do
        Write-Host "Okay - no changes $($_.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        #No, it's not compliant so let's remove any preceding numbers, spaces and dashes etc
        $MyFileObject = $_
        $MyFileObject.Name = $MyFileObject.Name.trimstart(" 0123456789-_.")
        #...and rename the file
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $MyFileObject.FullName -NewName "$($MyStudyNumber + ' - ' + $MyFileObject.Name)"
        Write-Host "Renamed to $($MyFileObject.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}
```

}

I'm have the same problem when using Windows 7 PowerShell v3 and 5.1

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the `Name` of the current `Get-ChildItem` object (in your case `$MyFileObject`).

This should work (part of your script):

```
$MyFileObject = $_
$FileName = $MyFileObject.Name.trimstart(" 0123456789-_.")

#...and rename the file
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $MyFileObject.FullName -NewName "$($MyStudyNumber + ' - ' + $FileName)"
Write-Host "Renamed to $FileName" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Comment: To have the terminal Write-Host return the true new `$FileName` I'd prepend the StudyNumber directly to it.

Comment: Thanks - the code now does the job.

Re Write-Host... That's still my problem in that my write-host cannot reference the true new file name. ...unless, as you say, by pre-pending $FileName with the $MyStudyNumber. Is there a way of referencing the new true filename without having to do this? ...such as from $MyFileObject? I've tried and cannot "see" the true new filename in the debugger.

Comment: @RobCodyStuff - the simplest is to simply add a line that defines the $Var before the `Rename-Item` command. then use it in both that line and the `Write-Host` line. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Working well now.